# Socket Connection Problem

Tags: java, sockets, blackberry, java-me, tcp

I am using Socket connection to establish connections in my application. I have a problem when establishing the tunnel with the server: the connection is being closed automatically after 3 minutes for example so when trying again to get data after 3 or 4 minutes, I will have an exception in the inputStream and outputStream. But the thread that opened the connection will not through any kind of exception since I included a `try{ ... } catch (Exception ex) { }`.
Now the question is, How to keep alive the socket connection to not close at all?

Comment: what exception do you get after 3/4 minutes?

Comment: And no exception is thrown after 3/4 minutes ... I am using catch (Exception ex) and no exception is thrown

Comment: AIX what do you mean by SSH Tunnel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is disucsse over on [BlackBerry support forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Connection-timeout-different-with-socket/m-p/22187). It is important to remember that when using a portable connected wireless device there are many reasons the connection might go down, and having a short timeout may be beneficial in cases where the connection may not be reliable:

- Fringe areas
- inside buildings
- moving

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `Socket.setKeepAlive(true)` ?

Comment: yes. I tried this. The connection is always getting idle after 3 or 4 minutes even with setKeepAlive(true)

Comment: tcp keepAlives are usually sent every few hours by default. Likely you have a firewall/nat gateway somwehere that closes the connection. You should peridically send some heartbeat message to the server if the protocol you're using allows it.